# WebView is not filling the whole width of a screen while loading local data

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I've got a simple layout with a single webview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I need to load data into webview from local resources.
I do it in such way:

```
String str = "100% valid html with doctype and other things";
view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

But sometimes it's not filling the whole width. You know, that there are slide-in effect while loading data into webview. So, while loading it sometimes slides to some part of a screen (usually to the half) and do not slide farther, and the content is not filling the whole width as a result. Bug is reproducing on many devices (the screenshot is from Sony Xperia S, also stably reproduced on some Samsung Galaxy S2).

Turning on hardware acceleration doesn't help.

**So, why do this bug occures? And how to solve it?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define viewport metadata to your local html. Developing html for mobile devices needs more careful consideration.

Try to read [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html).

Comment: Hm, thanks! Don't you know, will webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); and webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true); help without setting viewport in html?

Comment: No. You need to setUseWideViewPort(true) and set a proper viewport meta data in html.

Comment: No, as far as I understood setUseWideViewPort has to be set to false. In this situation viewport will be constrained to it's own dimensions (webview and viewport will be the same size). If setUseWideViewPort is set to true, horizontal scrolling can appeared. Right?

Comment: If you setUseWideViewPort to false, it is correct that webview and viewport will be the same size. Then if a web page set its own viewport, it will not work.

Comment: Html pages have to fit the screen (no horizontal scrolling or something like that, only vertical). If I set setUseWideViewPort to false and put in html such line – '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />', I will a achive needed behaviour, right?

Comment: setUseWideViewPort(true); and setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); will help you achieve your goal.

Comment: To achieve your goal. setUseWideViewPort(true), setLoadWithOverviewMode(true) and remove the viewport in your html. It works for any html pages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20947/discussion-between-faylon-and-nicolauusyes)

Comment: Adding `setting.setUseWideViewPort(true)` and `settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)` seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to  change the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`.

I has a problem like yours, and I solve the problem by make that change.